Migration from Spring Boot 2.2 to 3.2 and Java 8 to Java 21 - facing issues upgrading to Spring Authorization Server
I am currently in the process of migrating the application from Java 8 to Java 21 and Spring Boot 2.2 to Spring Boot 3.2.
I am currently facing trouble with security. My application has both an authorization server and a resource server which uses Spring security oauth2 of version 2.0.10 for authentication and authorization purposes.
The dependency I was using for it was
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

My authorization server class is as
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancerChain;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    private static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    private static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    private static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    private static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    private static final String TRUST = "trust";
    private static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 60 * 60;
    private static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6 * 60 * 60;
    
    
    @Value("${auth.server.client.id}")
    private String clientId;
    
    @Value("${auth.server.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    
    @Value("${auth.server.signing.key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomTokenEnhancer customTokenEnhancer;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {
        clientDetailsServiceConfigurer.inMemory().withClient(clientId)
                .secret(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST).accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(customTokenEnhancer, accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).exceptionTranslator(e -> {
                    if (e instanceof OAuth2Exception oAuth2Exception) {
                        return ResponseEntity.status(oAuth2Exception.getHttpErrorCode())
                                .body(new OAuth2Exception(oAuth2Exception.getMessage()));
                    } else {
                        throw e;
                    }
                });
    }

}


I couldn't find proper solution to upgrading this server to new Spring Authorization Server with custom token enhancer and jwt token converter.
Is there any way to incorporate it with the new Spring Authorization Server?

As announced, Spring Security OAuth is no longer supported and has reached end-of-life, and is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.x.
Spring Authorization Server is a separate project and does not extend from or inherit from the deprecated Spring Security OAuth project so there is no direct way to upgrade. Spring Security also has built-in support for resource server as well. Please see the reference documentation for Spring Authorization Server and OAuth2 Resource Server.
